# How to clear console programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have a bunch of NSLog statements in my code which I use for debugging. Every time I run my Project I'd like to start from a fresh console screen. Is there any command I can embed in my code which can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could use the "Auto Clear Debug Console" setting in the Xcode Preferences...

Don't know if this answers your question?

Comment: Dear @NsExplorer, Actually this is not answer you want. 'Command + K' Actually this is the action you want. How can we execute this action with code(programmatically)?

Answer (score 85):

When in the console (Debug mode), use:

```
Xcode > Debug > Debug Workflow > Clear Console
```

Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 23):

## Swift

```swift
print("any value", terminator: Array(repeating: "\n", count: 100).joined())
```

## Objective-C

I think the only thing you can is

```
for(int i= 0; i < 100; i++) 
NSLog(@" ");
```

just like in good old MS-DOS :)

Comment: This answer just made my day! (even tough I won't use it) :)

Comment: This won't really clear it though since it will include all of your debug data since you are using NSLog. You should instead use `puts(" ");`

Comment: C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

Comment: Not really clearing the console...   But.... OK....   It may help...    I would not use it in any code to be committed.... (like adding a \n to add clarity to the console readout)      It is brute force on steroids

Answer (score 10):

If you are talking about the console in the Xcode window there is a "Clear Console" option in the "Run" menu. There is also, in the "Debugging" Preferences tab an "Auto Clear Debug Console" checkbox. I am referring Xcode 3.2.x

Comment: hmm you where first... :-(    :-)

Answer (score 3):

The debugger console / run log are basically a redirected "log this to the console" command from your app. "Clearing" it means nothing in the general sense, since the messages are usually just shunted somewhere (like a file). Your application would have to know about its debugging environment and be able to tell that environment to clear whatever it's logging to.

In short: I suppose it's not *impossible* but it's ridiculously inconvenient.

Comment: However we can imagine a breakpoint command that basically asks the console to clear itself. _That_ would be convenient.

Comment: I upvote this idea of a breakpoint command that clears all to that point, and does not stop

Answer (score 2):

I went through all the answers and there are some alternatives but I think that the final answer is: You can not (as of Jun 2021).

The only alternative I use is:  Add a breakpoint. When the execution hits the breakpoint, click Ctr-K.  Resume execution.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by stackr, the "Auto Clear Debug Console" setting in the XCode Preferences will do this. To do it in code:

```
bool ClearXCodeDebuggerConsole()
{
    NSString *const scriptText = @"\
tell application \"System Events\"\n\
set currentapp to the name of the current application\n\
end tell\n\
tell application \"Xcode\" to activate\n\
tell application \"System Events\"\n\
keystroke \"r\" using {command down, control down, option down}\n\
end tell\n\
tell application currentapp to activate\n\
return true";

    NSAppleScript *script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptText] autorelease];
    [scriptText release];
    NSDictionary *dictError = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&dictError];

    if (!result) return false;
    if ([result booleanValue] != YES) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I'm looking for, but NSAppleScript is part of AppKit. Do you know of an iOS version?

Answer (score -5):

command + control + options + R clears the console in xcode

Comment: this doesn't clear the console but it does add an empty line for each time you run the command which can be helpful.